# In what sense did Judas betray Jesus?

Tags: gospels, judas

> Mark 14:11: And when they heard [it], they were glad, and promised to
>   give him money. And he sought how he might conveniently **betray** him

and all other verses mentioning Judas betraying Jesus.

In what sense did Judas betray Jesus? Is it only in the sense of "giving Him away" to the soldiers by revealing His whereabouts or in the sense of breaking some important promise given to Jesus? I don't recollect any such episode in the Gospels when Judas would promise to be faithful to Jesus (like, for example, what Peter did).

Does the Greek word "betray" in all these cases related to Judas imply breaking some vow or promise?

On the other hand, if it's the "give away" sense, then it looks to me a bit contradictory to these words:

> Are ye come out as against a thief with swords and staves for to take
>   me? I sat daily with you teaching in the temple, and ye laid no hold
>   on me (Matthew 26:55)

Indeed, Jesus was not a criminal and wasn't hiding, so it was not really a hard task, I think, to find Him. At least, there wasn't a need, I think, in finding "someone of His men" who would give Him away. Soldiers could have just asked crowds or just waited until Jesus came to the temple again.

Can anyone, please, explain this to me?

Comment: Also asked on [Christianity SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/in-what-sense-did-judas-betray-jesus).

Comment: Putting Jesus' life in imminent danger?

Comment: Perhaps they don't dare to arrest Jesus publicly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Jewish leaders wanted to arrest and kill Jesus quietly because they were afraid of how the people might react.  Matthew 26:3-5 says,

> Then the chief priests and the elders of the people were gathered together in the court of the high priest, named Caiaphas; and they plotted together to seize Jesus by stealth and kill Him. But they were saying, 'Not during the festival, otherwise a riot might occur among the people.'

Their concern about a riot can also be seen in how quickly they took Jesus to trial - the very night he was arrested. It was illegal for the Sanhedrin to try capital cases at night (Babylonian Talmud, Sanhedrin 32a, in the mishna), yet that is exactly what they did with Jesus. Before the rooster crowed the next morning, the Sanhedrin had condemned him to death. (Matthew 26:66, 74) The decision had to be ratified by the Romans, and I think that took longer than the Jewish leaders hoped. Never-the-less Jesus was on the cross before noon the next day. (Matthew 27:45)

So the evil of what Judas did is that he helped the chief priests and elders locate Jesus in a secluded spot away from the crowds.

Comment: Actually they also attempted to get the trial done quietly. It was illegal for the Sanhedrin to try capital cases at night, yet that is exactly what they did with Jesus.  Before the rooster crowed the next morning, the Sanhedrin had condemned him to death.  (Matthew 26:66, 74) The decision had to be ratified by the Romans, and I think that took longer than the Jewish leaders hoped. Never-the-less Jesus was on the cross before noon the next day.  (Matthew 27:45)

Comment: How many of the Sanhedrin wanted Jesus killed? Are most of them around at that time?

Comment: Reading more into the history and details of these events, we can truly see what a wicked and perverse generation that was.  (Matthew 16:4)

Comment: I am glad i have found this answer. This question always troubled me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been reading around this and studying this question too.
I think Judas' betrayal happened a long time before this event in many small but accumulative ways.
He had already betrayed Him in his heart many times before this final event.
We are told he was a thief and took money from the common purse.
He was choosing Mammon over Jesus every time he did that.
Who knows how many times? The gospels do not tell us.
The sin was unchecked by himself, not repented of, and habitual.

This was his final betrayal but the actual betrayal had begun sometime ago.
Don't despise the day of small things works both ways.
He who is faithful in little will be faithful in much and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (both bottom left, below) regarding the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Judas was the one who handed Him over to His enemies.

> Then Satan entered Judas, called Iscariot, one of the Twelve. And Judas went to the chief priests and the officers of the temple guard and discussed with them how he might betray Jesus. **They were delighted and agreed to give him money. He consented, and watched for an opportunity to hand Jesus over to them when no crowd was present.** Luke 22:3-6

And with the kiss of a friend to boot.

> **Now the betrayer had arranged a signal with them: “The one I kiss is the man; arrest him and lead him away under guard.” Going at once to Jesus, Judas said, “Rabbi!” and kissed him.** The men seized Jesus and arrested him. Mark 14:44-46