# Why did Judas express remorse only after he saw that Jesus was condemned?

Tags: matthew, jesus, judas

Related: [In what sense did Judas betray Jesus?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5520/in-what-sense-did-judas-betray-jesus)

*Very* related: [Does Scripture imply that Judas knew that the high-priests and elders' goal was to have Jesus killed?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/does-scripture-imply-that-judas-knew-that-the-high-priests-and-elders-goal-was)

From Matthew 26:14-16:

> Then one of the Twelve—the one called Judas Iscariot—went to the chief priests and asked, “What are you willing to give me if I deliver him over to you?” So they counted out for him thirty pieces of silver. From then on Judas watched for an opportunity to hand him over.

From Matthew 27:3:

> When Judas, who had betrayed him, saw that Jesus was condemned, he was seized with remorse and returned the thirty pieces of silver to the chief priests and the elders.

Why was he filled with remorse only after he saw that Jesus had been condemned? He had evidently planned the betrayal out very carefully and well in advance, so why then? Given the fact that [he seems to have known about the plot to kill Jesus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40553/how-did-judas-know-when-to-go-to-the-high-priests), why does he seem surprised by this outcome?

Comment: Is not it in the very nature of every sin? One fornicates, and just before and during the fornication he may not think of the consequence, but feel a kind of unreflected bliss; but when the affair is ended, he, then only, feels emptiness, pangs of conscience, remorse, self-loath even; Judas - no way different: he gradually had been betraying Jesus, getting annoyed with His supra-national and supra-practical teachings, clinging to his own limited understanding of Messiah; eventually, this logically led him to the outright treason of his Teacher. But then conscience and with it remorse returned.

Comment: Judas might have thought we as forcing Jesus' hand to use the power he showed during miracles to take over the situation.  Instead Jesus willingly gave up his life John 10:18.  But if so, Judas didn't listen.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili That could be an answer.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thanks for your comment; glad if my response was of use for you!

Answer (score 1):

Levan Gigineishvili's comment made an excellent point:

> he may not think of the consequence

Further, there are people who are incapable of thinking about what could happen two steps later. It is too distant and too abstract for them. They can only see the present if that.

He had evidently planned the betrayal out very carefully and well in advance, so why then?

I think you have given Judas too much credit for his intellectual planning,
John 13:

> 26 Jesus answered, “It is the one to whom I will give this piece of bread when I have dipped it in the dish.” Then, dipping the piece of bread, he gave it to Judas, the son of Simon Iscariot. 27As soon as Judas took the bread, **Satan** entered into him.

Satan entered into his plan.

> So Jesus told him, “What you are about to do, do quickly.”

It wasn't even Judas' timing.

Given the fact that he seems to have known about the plot to kill Jesus, why does he seem surprised by this outcome?

Because Judas wasn't a logical thinker.

Matthew 27:

> 1 Early in the morning, all the chief priests and the elders of the people made their plans how to have Jesus **executed**. 2So they bound him, led him away and handed him over to Pilate the governor.

Now the picture of execution became more physical and real to Judas.

> 3 When Judas, who had betrayed him, saw that Jesus was **condemned**, he was seized with remorse and returned the thirty pieces of silver to the chief priests and the elders.

He had not thought or planned this far ahead.

> 5 So Judas threw the money into the temple and left. Then he went away and hanged himself.

If Judas were being logical, he wouldn't have killed himself.

Why did Judas express remorse only after he saw that Jesus was condemned?

Because things were not so real to him until then. He couldn't perceive the logical consequences of his betrayal ahead of time. He might even have thought that Jesus would get out of this by calling on legions of angels.

Answer (score 0):

Anne Catherine emmerich said Judas did not know that Jesus was going to die see wisdom 2:18 which Loosely says if God is his father he will protect him we are playing God with Judas only God knows whether Judas repented or not see chapter 1486 in the Divine Mercy diary entitled Divine Mercy in my soul read it all that's so despairing is saved the catechism of the Catholic church today this is Judas only in paragraph 1851 and it speaks of Mercy not condemnation is Thomas Aquinas might say all these comments by people are straw I say with charity my comments are probably straw to we don't know where Judas is he may be in purgatory till the end of time as Amelia is according to the Virgin Mary and Fatima let us not judge each other Saint Paul says he does not judge he doesn't even judge himself and he should know his sins let us stop judging Judas and pray for his soul saying he is a he is in hell prevents people from praying for him this is a greater sin then we care think about for ourselves to commit. which we will be judged for.  As we judge so we will be judged, therefore stop judging Judas and pray for him .
thank God for Jesus Mary and Joseph

Comment: Weird question: can you [edit] to add additional punctuation and paragraph breaks? I'm having a little trouble following it right now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).